# Why Python tk entry default text is not showing path but normal text?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am writing a GUI with python 3.6 tkinter. running the code below could come out with the picture as below with "Hello World" as default text:

However, it doesn't work when I replace `entryvalue='Hello World'` with `entryvalue='C:\Users\User\Document'`

Does anyone know why and how to solve this? I want to show the default text is the file path. Thank you in advance

[image]
the code is working well as below:

```html
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# tkinter GUI
root= tk.Tk() 
root.title("Entry Box Testing") 

root.geometry('600x300+50+10')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
    
canvas.pack() 

label = tk.Label(root, text='File Path: ')
canvas.create_window(20, 50, window=label,anchor='nw')

entryvalue='Hello World'
v = StringVar(root, value=entryvalue)
entry = tk.Entry (root,textvariable=v,width=40) 
entry.pack()
canvas.create_window(20, 80, window=entry,anchor='nw')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you try with a raw string?: `entryvalue=r'C:\Users\User\Document'`

Comment: @mechanical_meat you are right! that solve. But still don't know why, I just want to treat it as string

Comment: This is because backslashes in regular strings can be escape characters. You need to use the raw string, or escape the backslashes like this: `'C:\\Users\\User\\Document'`

Comment: Does it mean regular expression made it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't have to do with regular expressions.

Comment: What does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error?